# Cannot get websocket connection working with ec2 + application load balancer

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, websocket, amazon-alb

I have an aws application load balancer with an https listener on port 9999, forwarding to a group on port 9999 with an ec2-instance being the target.

If I run my websocket server with the host name configured to my domain `api.example.com`, then when the client tries to open a websocket connection it gets:

> Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 502

However, if I configure my websocket server with an empty string instead of the domain, then it connects **just fine**!

This is problematic because the server I am intending to run on this instance automatically launches a websocket server **ONLY IF** there is a websocket host name configuration provided, so a blank string means the websocket server will never launch!  I would prefer to not have to hack the library to get around that condition.  So I am wondering, why in the world a blank string works, but the domain name does not?

I tried localhost, the ip of the box, etc, everything results in a 502 except a blank string!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was solved by setting my websocket server host to 0.0.0.0

Comment: To explain why this works, `localhost` or `127.0.0.1` is only accessible through other local devices. `0.0.0.0` means 'no particular address' [source](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0), and in this context, this means let the application bind to all addresses. [What does it mean to bind() a socket to any address other than localhost?](https://superuser.com/questions/949428/whats-the-difference-between-127-0-0-1-and-0-0-0-0)

Answer (score 1):

The ALB does not use a host name for the health check. Thus, if your server does not support requests without host names, the health check will fail, resulting in 5xx errors when accessing the ALB.

- Check the target group the ALB is using for health check errors
- Check your application server logs for health check related errors

If your server does not support this you have two options:

- Use a proxy (e.g. nginx) on your server that can handle requests without host name, and handle the problem there
- Override the ALB health check port, redirecting it to something that returns HTTP 200 all the time (e.g. an Apache running on the same host, but on another port).

Comment: sorry, this has nothing to do with the health check. I actually had no idea how to do a "health check" for a websocket server, so I just made the health check go to my webserver (https 443) just to get it to pass.  So the target on my port 9999 group is in fact "healthy."  As I said, I can connect via websockets just fine only if I run the websocket server without a host name, and that is a problem as I need to specify a host name.